# how to connect 2 nodes by dragging and creating a bridge between them in unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, unity3d-editor

In unity 3D I want to create a game where the user gets to create a 3D bridge between two 3D islands. I'm new to unity/C#. So I need some suggestions on what should I use and how to use them. I'm looking for a step by step instructions on this issue or some chunks of code that I can edit and combine. (I've seen some 2D videos about it, but they're not so helpful in my situation)

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi stack is here for you help but instead of taking it as a pool to get code chunks please share what you have tried and what problems you are facing implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is more about helping users with specific coding questions:

[image: Sidebar on the Stack Overflow "Ask a Question" page]

You should post general game development questions like these to the [Game Development SE site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Sidebar on the Game Development "Ask a Question" page]

On both sites you should be showing some amount of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself, though the GameDev site generally has different threshold on that; posting a few links to the tutorials you've seen and describing why it doesn't work for you (more than "but they're not so helpful in my situation") should suffice. The Game Development SE site is more open towards general discussions about coding, practices, methodologies, etc, as they apply to game dev.